# C program confusing output

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main(){

        int main =22;
        printf("%d\n",main);
        return 0;
}
```

output:22
I am defining main as function and variable both even though compiler is not giving error. It should give error "error: redefinition of ‘main’ " . I am not able to understand why this code is working.

Comment: Take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will not give you an error because `main` is not a keyword. `but main is define 2 times` - Scoping rules come into play.

Comment: but main is define 2 times . first as function and second as variable.

Comment: `but main is define 2 times` - Scoping rules comes into play.

Answer (score 3):

The *main* function is in the global scope - while the variable *main* is defined within the function *main* scope. They're not at the same level, thus there is no conflict.

The `int main=22;` line tells the compiler to use (declare) the local variable *main* - there is no conflict / ambiguity.

Do

```
int main(){

    return 0;
}

int main =22;
```

on the other hand and you'll get an error.

Answer (score 3):

The declaration of `main` inside the function creates a new identifier in the scope of the function. It does not override the `main` function which is defined in global scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


void stuff();
main()
{
   int val = 10;
   printf("from main: %d\n", val);

   stuff();

   printf("from main: %d\n", val);

   stuff();
}

void stuff()
{
    int val = 5;
    printf("from stuff: %d\n", val);
}
```

It doesn't matter defining the int val many times as it matters in which scope it's defined, this will output 10 5 10 5 , no errror no bad behavior